# How to generate scaffold with scoping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

One scaffold is "country" and the other scaffold is "state". Now one country can have many state and each state can belongs to one country.

I know how to create (controller, Model and View) scaffold and routes using the command line generator like below:

```
rails g scaffold admin/country name:string
rails g scaffold admin/state country:references name:string
```

But we should change the routing manually for "state" scope under "country" like below to get a url: `http://localhost:3000//admin/countries/2/states`.

```
resources :countries do
  resources :states
end
```

Also, we should change the "link" in State's View and State's Controller to get it work perfect.

Now, My question is:

> How to generate the scaffold with scoping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaffolding is intended to create a "mostly-useful-starting-point", in other words, you start from the templates the scaffolding created, and modify them case by case to suit your needs. I consider the case you describe as "special", in that most models are not nested. As such, I consider it normal practise to generate the files by scaffolding, and afterwards edit the files to suit your needs.

If you read the blogs etc., you will find out that most "experienced" users don't use scaffolding anymore. Some others, and I'm one of them, have changed the default scaffolding to better suit "their needs and their style"...